# Bash: Archiving 30 days or older files

Tags: bash

I'm having the hardest time finding out how to do a fairly simple task succesfully:
Archive files and folders to a different location (eg cp -rp /source/file /destination/file)
Remove them once coppied (rm -rf /source/file)
But only if they are 30+ days or older, which I know requires find -mtime 30. But I do not know how to make the following code work with find:

```
#!/bin/bash

#functions
help()
{
echo "archiveer <doelmap>
archiveer /home/goedvoorbeeld/testmap

Dit commando zorgt ervoor dat gebackupte users van meer dan 30 dagen oud worden gearchiveerd. Alleen de meest recente data wordt opgeslagen.
De doelmap parameter is verplicht.";
exit
}

doemaar()
{
echo "Doe maar wordt uitgevoerd"
for f in *; do
    if [[ "${f}" -nt "${doelmap}${f}" ]]
    then
    echo "file $f is nieuwer of niet aanwezig, gebacked up"
    cp -rp "$f" "${doelmap}${f}"
    rm -rf "$f"
    else
    echo "file $f is ouder"
    fi
done
}

#check for parameters
if [[ $1 = "help" ]]
then
help
elif [[ $1 = "" ]]
then
echo "Missende parameter!"
help
fi

#set variables
doelmap=$1

#script gaat runnen
echo "${doelmap}" && sleep 1

if [ ! -d "${doelmap}" ]
then
mkdir -p "${doelmap}"
echo "${doelmap} is gemaakt"
else
echo "doelmap bestaat al"
fi
doemaar
echo "Script end"
```

Comment: what if the folder is >30 days but its contents aren't? Or the contents are >30 days but the folder isn't?

Comment: why `cp`+`rm` instead of just `mv` ?

Comment: It's only about the contents within the folder. The date of each folder is irrelevant. And the cp+rm instead of mv was because I had split it up with different steps before publishing the code here and I didn't bother correcting it

Answer (score 0):

Note that * can sometimes cause problems if filenames have spaces or special characters in them.  That is why I always redirect any lists to a file, from which I work from.  Also, the results list from * might exceed shell limits, causing different issues.

Also, "-rp" implies recursive, so directory contents.  But earlier you stated that you were only looking at files.  So the assumption is that there are no sub-directories under the directory where you are trying to find old files.

I would process the file archiving, then I would check the parent directories to purge directories that are left empty after the archiving.  This is a safety measure in case of power loss.

You could consider adapting the following into your script:

```
cd "${LIVE_DIR}"
TOPIC=`basename "${LIVE_DIR}" `
find . -type f -mtime 30+ -print >joblist.files

mkdir "${ARCHIVE_ROOT}/${TOPIC}"
if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then  echo "unable to create dir" ; exit 1 ; fi

while read file
do
  ARC_FILE="${ARCHIVE_ROOT}/${TOPIC}/${file}"

  cp -pv "${file}" "${ARC_FILE}"
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]
  then  rm -f "${file}"
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]
        then  echo "PURGE|rm -f \"${file}\"" >&2
        fi
  else  rm -fv "${ARC_FILE}"
        echo "ARCHIVE|cp -pv \"${file}\" \"${ARC_FILE}\"" >&2
  fi

  echo "LAST|${file}" >joblist.last

done <joblist.files 2>joblist.failed
```

**joblist.failed** contains any cleanup that needs to be performed, commands that need to be repeated to complete the initial job.

**joblist.last** contains the last file processed if you need to kill the job and keep track of where you left off.